# How to created virtualenv in ubuntu outside the built in memory

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtualenv in ubuntu 20.04, I am facing this error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/bin/python3'.

I am trying to create the virtualenv not using the built-in memory but the memory card connected to the system.

Any solutions? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Show us your mount, the command line, the full output and the permissions of the target directory!

Comment: Run `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: putwind@putwind:/media/putwind/Card/My_Projects/First_Project$ ls -l
total 128
drwxr-xr-x 4 putwind putwind 131072 May  7 17:45 vb
these are the permissions of  the dir, one more thing it create the "env_name" dir but bin dir is empty

--------------------------
 ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May  2 23:09 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8

Comment: You don't have the proper permissions to write to the external storage.

Comment: What is the solution for the that?

Comment: @Klaus D. also if i don't have proper permissions then there should not be any folder created, but while creating the virtual env one dir is getting created but nothing in the bin dir. I new to ubuntu , might be missing something.